# import datetime versus from datetime import datetime

Tags: python, python-3.x, typeerror, python-import, python-datetime

I trying to set a datetime with timezone information. In this case UTC.

when I try this code, it works:

```
from datetime import datetime, timezone
prueba = timezone.utc

fecha = datetime(1900, 1, 1, 1, 00, 00, 00000, tzinfo=prueba)
```

but when I try this one, it faults with a "TypeError: 'module' object is not callable"

```
import datetime
prueba = datetime.timezone.utc

fecha = datetime(1900, 1, 1, 1, 00, 00, 00000, tzinfo=prueba)
```

It doesn't make sense to me because I'm referring to the same class I suppose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference is that the `datetime` module includes a `datetime` class. When you do:

```
from datetime import datetime, timezone
```

You are importing the `datetime.datetime` class, and calling it `datetime` and the `datetime.timezone` class, and calling it `timezone`.

When you do

```
import datetime
```

what you are doing is importing the whole datetime module.`datetime` now refers to the `datetime` module, not the `datetime.datetime` class. The `datetime` class needs to be called as `datetime.datetime()`.

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer, but it has not sens to me, datetime.datetime is a class, not a function. So in case it was importing datetime.datetime() as datetime as a class then the second code sample must work using datetime.datetime().utc (which didn't work) but datetime.utc definition is out of datatime class definition in datetime.py:

    timezone.utc = timezone._create(timedelta(0))

Comment: I leave this hear for other one that need it. The second code sample must be that way: import datetime
prueba = datetime.timezone.utc

fecha = datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 1, 00, 00, 00000, tzinfo=prueba)